# How to publish a new religious study tool/study guide that is still a continuing work?

Tags: self-publishing, first-time-author

I have been studying the Bible in order to gain a coherent and comprehensive understanding of my Lord Jesus Christ. I narrowed the focus into the 4 Gospels. I then focused even more within the Gospels concerning the Cross of Jesus Christ. From the garden of Gethsemane unto Jesus returning to the Father.

I studied how the original authors that were guided by the spirit propounded their work from various sources including their own experience. I can't include my own experience because I wasn't there. With that in mind I used the four Gospels as my source and formed a comprehensive coherent account of Jesus from the garden to the grave and from the grave into the sky.

Then I converted it into first person. I changed not a word but used the wording of the King James bible. Only changes made in order to format it correctly were that of person and verb tenses to agree with Jesus being 1st person. Each line is tagged with the original Gospel source for reference purposes. I hand wrote. It is revelatory in the fact that it gives the account in a chronological and conceptual fashion that I believe could be an excellent study aid for gospel enthusiasts.

What do I need to do next with the manuscript? I have a digital, fully edited and complete section, concerning the Garden of Gethsemane for the purpose of review. I am in the process of converting the rest into digital format right now. I feel moved to do this to the entirety of the Gospels. This is just a study tool to assist students in acquiring a complete chronological and coherent understanding of what happened. I used the King James Version and in such a way that all existing tools, strongs, vines, interlinears, etc. all still correspond. It's neat.

What should I do to make this accessible and hopefully credible to other people?

Comment: In what sense do you mean 'credible'? Are you trying to produce an apocryphal first person account of the life of Jesus?

Comment: I mean credible as in legitimate. And I love your term. I am an apocalyptic evangelist. I cite all my source material as I go in the left margin. My sources of course are the four Gospels which I think lends credibility to it but I am a nobody with no published work. I need help.

Comment: Hi welcome to the site! What do you think you should do next? (Find experts to review? Try to get a professional-looking cover? Set up a blog?) Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: What to do next depends on your goal. Do you want to publish it for money, or do you just want to make it available to others in the easiest way possible?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much you have to finish it. No publisher is going to do anything with it unless you present it in its final form.

If you are a beginning author with no track record of previous publications, it makes zero difference how interesting your work-in-progress sounds or reads or anything else. It must be finished completely and ready to publish before anybody will even look at it; unless you have some personal friend to do that, or unless you can find a paid reviewer to do it for you. That latter will be costly; figure a few dollars per page.

And you will find virtually nobody, in this day and age, willing to review or consider hand-written work. Perhaps some scam artists. This must be 100% transmissible as an email attachment.

All I would bother doing at this point is start to research agents interested in religious works. This site might help: [How to Find a Literary Agent.](https://www.janefriedman.com/find-literary-agent/)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question since you're talking about traditional publishing. It looks like OP plans to self-publish, hence the tag on the question.

Comment: @Laurel I did not notice the tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish traditionally, you'll have to finish the work first.

I'm not sure exactly if your work would be considered fictional or non-fictional, but non-fictional projects might be proposed to publishers with only a chapter or two done as a sample. (Although I don't know much about non-fictional publishing).

If, on the other hand, you're okay to publish it non-traditionally, you could do that online as a blog, wiki, or some other format.

I've even seen people starting out writing a number of blog articles they then put together into a self-published book and sold. (Which works extra well if the blog ends up with a larger following...)

If you decide to go the online-non-traditional route I suggest doing it via something like a blog, rather than publishing chapters on places like Amazon.

Chances are you'll realize you want to do some changes in previous chapters or parts as you tackle later chapters/parts, and a blog (or even a wiki) would let you do that easily.